# Extract value by desired key, from IEnumerable<CustomModel>

Tags: c#, .net, key, ienumerable

I have CustomModel class with two properties, Key and Value:

```
public class CustomModel 
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Also, I have `IEnumerable<CustomModel>` object. Assume there are 100 items in that object and one of them has `Key = "Age"` with `Value = "50"`. How to extract only that item from object? Actually, I need to pass key "Age" and get value "50".

Comment: Ever heard of LINQ? It let's you do things like `var result = IEnumerable<CustomModel>.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key=="Age")` Another possibility is to use a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead of inventing your own.

Comment: Why use your own type for that if a `KeyValuePair<string, string>` does exactly this? A list of those is then a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Comment: `var item = object.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key=="Age")` returns whole item, but I need only its Value. How can I do it in one line, by not doing `item.Value` in next line? EDIT: it will be `object.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key=="Age").Value`

Comment: "" Actually, I need to pass key "Age" and get value "50"."" You want a `Dictionary<string,string>` instead of a `CustomModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

    `var dict = listOfModels.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    var sample = dict["Age"] // should be 50`